# == and Equals for Tuple<object>

Tags: c#, object, tuples, equality

i have a question why it works like this

```
var a = new Tuple<object, object, object>(1, 1, 1);
var b = new Tuple<object, object, object>(1, 1, 1);

Console.WriteLine(a.Item1==b.Item1);//Output- False
Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));//Output- True
Console.WriteLine(a==b);//Output- False
```

Why so ?

i try to find some info about how it works, as far as i know this happens because of object type, and value type(int)

Comment: You realise that the first compare has nothing to do with tuples? As you are comparing two boxed ints?  maybe you want to read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing

Comment: It's 2024 now. `Tuple` has been mostly obsolete since C# 7 came out more than 6 years ago... **especially** `Tuple<object ... >`. Instead, this should really be a `ValueTuple<int, int, int>`, which you can define like this: `var a = (1, 1, 1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the different between [value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) and [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) types in C#.

> Console.WriteLine(a.Item1==b.Item1);//Output- False

Here you're comparing two `object` instances. As for any reference type, the equality operator (unless overriden in that type) does reference comparison.

When you store any value type (e.g. `int` in your case) in the variable of reference-type (`object` in your case), you're doing what's named [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing).

> Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));//Output- True

This is because `Equals` method is overriden in the `Tuple` type to check if its content are identical to another tuple. It is calling `Equals` for each of the items and return `true` if all of them are equal.

> Console.WriteLine(a==b);//Output- False

Again, you have two instances of the `Tuple` class (any class is a reference type), and that `Tuple` class doesn't have override for an `==` operator. Therefore, you're just checking if those two variables containing the same instance.

Comment: FYI you seem to have mixed up what the line `Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));` is actually comparing. You seem to think its comparing ints and not the tuples.

Comment: @RandRandom right, my bad. Corrected the answer